How to get the Friday date from a week start date
In Excel, given a date like 3/17/2024, how can I get the date corresponding to Friday in the same week?

Try using WEEKDAY() function:


=B2+7-WEEKDAY(B2+1)


Or, the above will be dynamic as it will return the second last week ending day, but if you are going to enter the first day of the week always and which is Sunday and need the Friday then simply use;
=B2+5



You can set Sunday or Monday to be the week start day in Excel iirc.

@SolarMike true Sir. Sir what is iirc

iirc is If I Remember Correctly... Still a good answer.

@SolarMike Sir, ah cool, thanks I dont know these short forms thanks again!

@Mayukh Bhattacharya Thank you very much for such a clear response. This actually helped.
